# Website on godaddy, domain on wix. How can connect specific folder with DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I have many different websites on my godaddy account.
root > folder1
root > folder2
etc.

I understand the basics of pointing the DNS to the godaddy account, but how can I point a domain located on WIX to a specific folder to open which is hosted on godaddy? It won't just know to open that folder one its own just by pointing it to the ip of the godaddy server

Comment: This is a question for GoDaddy support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GoDaddy web server knows which website to display by the URL in the request. Each website should be tied to a hostname in GoDaddy.

So, even though each DNS entry will point to the same IP address, the web request will specify which website to display.

As an example, if you open Google Chrome and type in www.google.com, your browser converts www.google.com to an IP address and then sends a GET request to that IP. Within the GET request is the url www.google.com so that the Google web server knows which site you are requesting even though it may have many available at the same IP.

And, in fact, GoDaddy will be hosting dozens or hundreds of websites at the same IP address.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so if the domain is www.example1.com, how will it know after pointing it to a general godaddy account IP, to which folder to go? i dont want it to open the root folder.. i want it to go to "root > folder1" so that www.example1.com opens that specific folder

Comment: You can't use DNS to direct a client to a specific subfolder of a website. That's not what DNS is for. But, you can create multiple websites on GoDaddy and each one has a different hostname and is tied to a separate subfolder. i.e. beta.mysite.com -> /root/folder1; prod.mysite.com -> /root/folder2; myothersite.com -> /root/folder3

Comment: for the solution. it was pointing the records but the making an addon domain and that will know to find it! maybe that is what you said haha not sure

Comment: Yes, in principal that is what I said. I see GoDaddy calls them "addon" domains. I had forgotten that. But, the point is, each subfolder is tied to a different web address. Glad you got it figured out. Can you up vote my answer?